# PHP: convert date into seconds?

Tags: php

I've a date like **Tue Dec 15 2009**. How can I convert it into seconds?

Update:
How can I convert a date formatted as above to Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I assume by seconds you mean a [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

[strtotime()](http://de.php.net/strtotime) should help.

Comment: Yeah, UNIX timestamp! that's what i Meant. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 18):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) function to convert that date to a timestamp :

```
$str = 'Tue Dec 15 2009';
$timestamp = strtotime($str);
```

And, just to be sure, let's convert it back to a date as a string :

```
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $timestamp));
```

Which gives us :

```
string '2009-12-15' (length=10)
```

*(Which proves `strtotime` did understand our date ^^ )*

---

**[edit 2012-05-19] as some other questions might point some readers here:** Note that **`strtotime()`** is not the only solution, and that you should be able to work with the [**`DateTime`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which provides some interesting features -- especially if you are using PHP >= 5.3

In this case, you could use something like the following portion of code :

```
$str = 'Tue Dec 15 2009';
$format = 'D F d Y';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $str);
$timestamp = $dt->format('U');
```

[**`DateTime::createFromFormat()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) allows one to create a **`DateTime`** object from almost any date, no matter how it's formated, as you can specify the format you date's in *(This method is available with PHP >= 5.3)*.

And [**`DateTime::format()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) will allow you to format that object to almost any kind of date format -- including an [UNIX Timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), as requested here.

Comment: @Usman : you're welcome :-)  ;; well, I've sometimes have had bad surprises with strtotime (especially because I'm french and our dates format is not the same than the english one), so I prefer being careful ^^

Comment: This is the best answer, not the one checked.

Answer (score 6):

You mean like an UNIX-timestamp? Try:

```
echo strtotime('Tue Dec 15 2009');
```